# Referencing .NET Framework 4.5 Class Library project from CoCoa application

Tags: c#, .net, macos, cocoa, cross-platform

Is there any harm in referencing a .NET Framework 4.5 Class Library project from a Mac OSX CoCoa app?

I have heard that it is recommended to use .NET Standard for shared library code. However, there seems to be so many more API's available in .NET Framework 4.5 that are not available in .NET Standard 1.1 (i.e. System.IO.Directory.Create).

I am writing an OSx version of a Windows WPF application. I would ideally like to share the business logic code in a shared library opposed to duplicating.

The Windows project must remain on .NET 4.5, so if were to go .NET Standard route - it would need to be at 1.1, however many libraries are incompatible.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

I seem to be able to add a reference to a .NET Framework 4.5 Class Library and consume many of the libraries, and was wondering what the risks are here (if any).

Comment: Is that a Xamarin.Mac project? Don't use a term that nobody else uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any harm in referencing a .NET Framework 4.5 Class Library project from a Mac OSX CoCoa app?

Since .NET Framework 4.5 won't run on Mac OSX, I would say yes, there is harm.

> The Windows project must remain on .NET 4.5, so if were to go .NET Standard route - it would need to be at 1.1, however many libraries are incompatible.

If these "incompatible libraries" are 3rd party open source projects, the best thing to do is to help move them along by offering to contribute to upgrade to .NET Standard.

Do note that .NET Standard 1.1 is missing several APIs and many libraries need to either add more NuGet packages to add the missing APIs (see https://apisof.net/) or target a higher version than 1.1 in order to be compatible with .NET Standard. In the latter case, you can multi-target the library to .NET Framework 4.5 and also the minimum version of .NET Standard you can get away with. If you put both libraries into the same NuGet package, this is almost seamless.

Comment: Interesting - so I should definitely use .NET standard as my shared library....The odd thing is that referencing .NET Framework 4.5 actually seemed to work (at least on my mac) - was even able to create a directory using System.IO.Directory.Create, I imagine most of these APIs are unstable then?

Comment: I am not sure how your configuration is setup, but .NET Framework isn't designed to work on [any platform but Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems) (and Linux if you use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)). .NET Standard adds [true cross-platform support](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/1.0-supported-os.md). I would consider your specific case a fluke and assume that it won't work on any old OSX box unless you use .NET Standard.